# How to get wine prefix (where wine is installed)?

Tags: wine, winetricks

Web search finds only how to set wine prefix. I want to put wine-gecko files in appropriate place.

```
$ ls /usr/share/wine
ls: cannot access '/usr/share/wine': No such file or directory
```

According to the wine wiki page (see below) it means "you installed Wine in some $prefix rather than /usr,". I installed wine with something like `apt-get install winehq-stable`, how do I find out what prefix have it installed to? I've tried to use `winetricks`, but running `winetricks settings list` have not helped.

https://wiki.winehq.org/Gecko:

> When your application tries to display a site, Wine loads and uses its
> custom implementation of Gecko. Wine tries to find Gecko installation
> in following order:
>
> - If Wine Gecko is already installed in the prefix, that installation will be used.
> - Wine 5.0-rc1 and newer will try to load Gecko from UNIX-style installation without installing it into the prefix. It will look for -
>   wine-gecko-$(VERSION)-$(ARC) subdirectory of standard local lookup
>   (see bellow).
> - Wine will try to find Wine Gecko MSI installer on local machine (see bellow). If it can find it, it will install it into the prefix and use
>   it.
> - If the file can't be found on your computer, Wine will download it for you. The downloaded .msi is saved to ~/.cache/wine. If thedownload
>   fails, you can download the appropriate version (see table below)
>   yourself from http://dl.winehq.org/wine/wine-gecko/.
>
> Whenever Wine tries to find local installation, it will look in following directories:
>
> - In most cases, the file(s) should be placed in /usr/share/wine/gecko.
> - If you installed Wine in some $prefix rather than /usr, $prefix/share/wine/gecko/ before /usr/share/wine/gecko. (e.g. if you
>   installed it from source, then place the files in
>   /usr/local/share/wine/gecko).
> - If you're running Wine from build tree, Wine will try to find files in $build_dir/../gecko directory.
> - Local cache, usually ~/.cache/wine.

Comment: Why not use that last option, `~/.cache/wine`?

Comment: `dpkg -L winehq-stable` will tell you which files winehq-stable installed (with full paths).

Comment: @muru, for gecko to be available to all users.

Comment: @Henrik, I was able to find files. However, I want to put check into a script and also winehq-stable pulled many debs in dependencies. I guess `dpkg -L winehq-stable` does not search dependencies?